# Bind a Class Property that returns a list to a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, properties, bind

I have a file name that is found at multiple paths. I want to present this data to the user in the format of a DGV. I have a DGV with one text box column for the name, and another combobox column for the paths. I am having trouble getting the combobox column to bind to the property of the class that returns the paths.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Public Class fileTest
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property Paths As String()

    Public Sub New(ByRef _name As String, ByVal _paths As String())
        Me.FileName = _name
        Me.Paths = _paths
    End Sub

End Class

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim fileList As New BindingList(Of fileTest)

    fileList.Add(New fileTest("TEST", {"ABC", "123"}))

    Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = fileList
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns("FileName").DataPropertyName = "FileName"
    CType(Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Paths"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataPropertyName = "Path"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is horrible. HORRIBLE.

We eventually gave up using it and now just float a standard Combobox over the grid.